# How to call several external jpanels from other main class within the same java package?

Tags: java, swing

Below is the `search_menu` class containing a jpanel defined in a package named admin.

The package contains a main class also. How one can call the `search_menu` jpanel and other such panels defined externally within the same package from the main class using the `SetVisible()` method or something similar.

Here is my code:

```
package admin;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment;

public class Search_menu extends JPanel {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * Create the panel.
 */
public Search_menu() {
    setBackground(UIManager.getColor("Button.darkShadow"));

    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("New button");
    GroupLayout groupLayout = new GroupLayout(this);
    groupLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(btnNewButton)
                .addContainerGap(251, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    groupLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(25)
                .addComponent(btnNewButton)
                .addContainerGap(339, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    setLayout(groupLayout);

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use following method to visible the Jpanel

```
 setVisible(true)
```

Comment: I could count on one hand, the times I've needed to call `setVisible(true)` on a component that is not a top-level container.

Answer (score 1):

If all classes are in the same package then you can create an object of the class you want to call and then use its `setVisible` mehod

```
like apanel obj=new apnel()
obj.setVisible(true);
```